# Microphone not working on Lenovo G470

Tags: 12.04, pulseaudio

I used a Lenovo G470 laptop (Core i5 2410M processor, AMD Radeon 6370M and 2GB DDR3 RAM) and I installed Ubuntu 12.04.

I can't get the microphone to work.

I encountered this type of issue before in my old Acer Aspire One with Ubuntu 10.04/10.10, and installing PulseAudio Volume Control and tweaking a little solves the problem.

I tried the same solution to no avail in 12.04. I tried entering the alsa in terminal and my mic is not detected there.

Does anybody encountered a similar problem? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I too was experiencing the same problem for while, I was able to fix it by installing pulse audio volume control from USC and fiddling with its settings got my mic working.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found a way to the solution in http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2011304

1. Edit file `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` by hitting **Alt+F2** and run `gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`.
2. Add a new line and insert `options snd-hda-intel model=asus`
3. **Restart your computer**

The microphone will work, but the volume will be too low.

The thread I linked above shows that the next step is to run **PulseAudio Device Chooser** to adjust the input volume of the microphone. However, I can't find it in the **Ubuntu Software Center**. When I tried to install `padevchooser` from terminal, it is said that:

> Package padevchooser is not available, but is referred to by another
>   package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been
>   obsoleted, or is only available from another source

It seems that the tool is now replaced, and in **Ubuntu Software Center**, I found **PulseAudio Maanager** instead. After you've got it installed, run `paman` from **Alt+F2**.

[image: PulseAudio Manager]

Click on **Devices** tab. Select your input device from the list and click **Properties**. Then, adjust the input volume as you see fit.

[image: Adjust the input volume.]

Be careful, though, as setting the volume too high will provide a noisy recording.

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: Thank you! Works fine for my Lenovo G570. I didn't even have to make the second step (adjusting volume through PulseAudio Manager)